# Word order for adverb of frequency

Tags: adverbs, word-order

adverbs as (sometimes, seldom, usually) we can put into the beginning, end, between pronoun and verb

but the adverb 'always' sounds good only between pronoun and verb, in other cases, it sounds weird (Always, I do it in the morning AND I do it in the morning always)

**Usually/sometimes/seldom**, I do it in the morning

I do it in the morning **usually/sometimes/seldom**

I **ALWAYS/usually/sometimes/seldom** do it in the morning

question:

> Is it right, in terms of grammar, to put the adverb 'always' in the beginning and at the end of sentence *(Always, I do it in the morning AND I do it in the morning always)* although it sounds weird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether *always* comes at the beginning or the end will depend on context.

If you are asked

> Q: When do you do it?
>   A: I **always** do it in the morning.
>   A: I do it in the morning, **always**.

whereas

> Q: Do you **always** do it in the morning?
>   A: **Always**, I do it in the morning.
>   A: I do it in the morning, **always**.